Adapted IsNumeric check-function does not work as expected
I have this procedure to check the input of a cell (and it is working as expected):
' Check for validation in column P
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("P")) Is Nothing Then
    ' Loop through each changed cell in the target range
    For Each cell In Target
        ' Check if the cell value matches the specified pattern
        cellValue = cell.value
        ' Check if the value starts with 2 numbers representing the last 2 digits of the current or previous year followed by a dash
        ' and has a total length of 9 characters
        Do While Not IsValidYearFormat(cellValue) Or Len(cellValue) <> 9 Or Not AreLastSixDigitsNumeric(Right(cellValue, 6))
            ' Prompt the user to enter a new value
            newValue = InputBox("Ongeldige notatie BPS mutatienummer in cel " & cell.address & " in kolom P. De waarde moet beginnen met 2 cijfers die de laatste 2 cijfers van het huidige of vorige jaar vertegenwoordigen, gevolgd door een streepje en moet in totaal 9 karakters lang zijn." & vbCrLf & "Voer een nieuwe waarde in die aan de criteria voldoet:", "Nieuwe waarde invoeren", cell.value)
            If newValue = "" Then Exit Sub ' Exit if the user cancels the input box
            ' Validate the new value
            If Not IsValidYearFormat(CStr(newValue)) Or Len(newValue) <> 9 Or Not AreLastSixDigitsNumeric(Right(newValue, 6)) Then
                ' Display error message if the new value is invalid
                MsgBox "Ongeldige notatie. De waarde moet beginnen met 2 cijfers die de laatste 2 cijfers van het huidige of vorige jaar vertegenwoordigen, gevolgd door een streepje en moet in totaal 9 karakters lang zijn. Bovendien moeten de laatste 6 karakters cijfers zijn.", vbExclamation, "Formaatcontrole"
            Else
                ' Replace the original value with the new valid value
                cell.value = newValue
                ' Exit the loop if the value is valid
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Next cell
End If

I used this exact procedure and changed it a bit, but now the 'isnumeric' part is not working anymore:
' Check for validation in column O
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("O")) Is Nothing Then
    ' Loop through each changed cell in the target range
    For Each cell In Target
        ' Check if the cell value matches the specified pattern
        cellValue = cell.value
        ' Check if the value is all-numeric and is 7 characters long
        Do While Len(cellValue) <> 7 Or Not AreLastSixDigitsNumeric(cellValue)
            ' Prompt the user to enter a new value
            newValue = InputBox("Ongeldige notatie VBS mutatienummer in cel " & cell.address & " in kolom O. De waarde bestaan uit cijfers en 7 cijfers lang zijn." & vbCrLf & "Voer een nieuwe waarde in die aan de criteria voldoet:", "Nieuwe waarde invoeren", cell.value)
            If newValue = "" Then Exit Sub ' Exit if the user cancels the input box
            ' Validate the new value
            If Len(newValue) <> 7 Or Not AreLastSixDigitsNumeric(cellValue) Then
                ' Display error message if the new value is invalid
                MsgBox "Ongeldige notatie. De waarde moet beginnen met 2 cijfers die de laatste 2 cijfers van het huidige of vorige jaar vertegenwoordigen, gevolgd door een streepje en moet in totaal 9 karakters lang zijn. Bovendien moeten de laatste 6 karakters cijfers zijn.", vbExclamation, "Formaatcontrole"
            Else
                ' Replace the original value with the new valid value
                cell.value = newValue
                ' Exit the loop if the value is valid
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Next cell
End If

With this procedure, it does not matter what I enter (123456 or abcdef or 123abc etc.), every value is not accepted as numeric (and the popup with the error message returns).
Is there any simple explanation why the IsNumeric function does not work?

What is AreLastSixDigitsNumeric - is it a VBA function? Does it work as expected? That said: Have you debugged your code to check where it fails?

Where in your code such a IsNumeric function exist? I cannot see it... Do you mean AreLastSixDigitsNumeric? If so, without showing it nobody can help you. Even if I think you can simple use IsNumeric(right(cellValue, 6)). Just looking to the function name meaning... What do you mean by "error message returns"?

sorry, the 'AreLastSixDigitsNumeric' is just a reference to the IsNumeric function:
Function AreLastSixDigitsNumeric(value As String) As Boolean
' Check if the last 6 characters of the value are numeric
AreLastSixDigitsNumeric = IsNumeric(value)
End Function. What I meant by 'the error message returns' is that whatever I enter in the input box, I get the error message the input is not matching the criteria. and I get a the input box to change the input.

As you are checking if the length of the entered value is 7, it doesn't come to a surprise that the values 123456,  abcdef and 123abc are not accepted...

of course. Should/Could have figured this myself.
